# Can a precision-recall graph have an error bar?

Tags: standard-error, precision-recall

I have only ever seen a precision-recall graph with lines. Could a precision-recall curve have error bars? How would the error bar be computed?

Answer (score 2):

For having error bars, you need to have multiple number of measurements for the same *threshold*, so that you can calculate statistics such as deviation, and plot bars. This is also true for ROC curve. I’ve seen this is done via simply cross-validation, or bootstrapping. One example plotting error bars on the PR curve by splitting the data several times as train/test is [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261492351_Image_Auto-Annotation_using_a_Statistical_Model_with_Salient_Regions) work.

Comment: Given that precision-recall graphs are real numbers, I assume some sort of threshold bucketing would be necessary?

Comment: You don't need to. Set an array of thresholds, and produce multiple precision/recall values for each one.

Comment: That would require the ability to generate examples for the given threshold, correct?

Comment: These examples are your classifier’s outputs that can be generated several ways, e.g. cross validation or splitting the data several times as shown in the linked work.